# Changing variable name with javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, attributes

How to shift between variable names in jQuery and change them?

```
//predefined variables
var s1='';
var d2='';
//trying to change variables by .attr() parameter but no luck
$('body').on('click','span', function() {
var $(this).parent().attr('data-scan')=$(this).attr('id');
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-scan="s1"><span id="banana">Banana</span><span id="apple">Apple</span></div>
<div data-scan="d2"><span id="orange">Orange</span><span id="apple">Apple</span></div>
```

How can I change specific variables? I do't care about changing attr papameter, all I need is changing predefined global var parameters!

Comment: you're missing a quote to end your data-scan attribute `<div data-scan="s1">` and if you want that property to be blank initially do `<div data-scan="">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your html for the `data-scan` attributes is wrong, you have no closing quotes.

Secondly, you can the `data()` jquery function to access `data` attributes.

Thirdly, you cannot set values by using the `=` operator.

You want something like this:

```
 $(this).parent().data('scan', $(this).attr('id'));
```

or, without the `data()` function:

```
 $(this).parent().attr('data-scan', $(this).attr('id'));
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/TQhbY/)

---

To get the value you can do one of the following:

```
var dataScan = $(this).parent().data('scan');
```

or

```
var dataScan = $(this).parent().attr('data-scan');
```

---

Your **exact requirements** for setting a variable based on the data-scan value

Based on your comments and code, I think it has not been clear what you were trying to do. I think I have worked it out though and you want to use the `data-scan` value to determine which global variable should be set...

```
//predefined variables
var s1='';
var d2='';

$('body').on('click','span', function() {
    var variableType = $(this).parent().data('scan');
    var valueToSet = $(this).attr('id');
    if(variableType == "s1"){
       s1 = valueToSet;
    }
    else if(variableType == "d2"){
       d2 = valueToSet;
    }
});
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/y7cT4/) of what I think you are trying to do.

However, if you have lots of variables then it is not ideal to use so many if/else statements. So you could use the javascript `eval()` function.

```
var variableType = $(this).parent().data('scan');
var valueToSet = $(this).attr('id');

eval("" + variableType + " = '" + valueToSet + "';");
```

[See here for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/y7cT4/1/)

But be careful the your eval code is subjected to user injected values (not that javascript is safe from users anyway)

Comment: I need to change only specific predefined global variables .data() is not what I want

Comment: @user1482261: So use the second example, I already edited that in before your comment

Comment: @user1482261: I have added some code which I think is exactly what you need. It was not clear from your original question, but based on your comments and code I think this is what you are after?

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm looking for! But I plan to set 40-50 variables, maybe even more. This is only a small example of what i needed. Is thre any workaround? I can't afford to check for 40-50 if-esle's

Comment: @user1482261: check my update, should help you alot. The `eval` function works like magic, but don't overuse it!

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong syntax of [**attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

**Syntax: attr( attributeName , value)**

Change

```
var $(this).parent().attr('data-scan')=$(this).attr('id');
```

To

```
$(this).closest('div').attr('data-scan',$(this).attr('id'));
```

You code would be

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9aDnW/)**

```
$('body').on('click','span', function() {
    debugger
 $(this).closest('div').attr('data-scan',$(this).attr('id'));

    s1=$(this).closest('div').attr('data-scan');
    alert(s1);
});​
```

Comment: and how to store data-scan variable in global var?

Comment: You have alread declared global variable assign value to it in click event like this, s1=$('[data-scan=s1]').attr('id');

Comment: @Adil, that is wrong, it will conflict with the other part of his question. Which is changing the `data-scan` value

Comment: I can't define every variable like s1 one-by-one, threre will be 40-50 variables I want to change! This is only a small example with 2 different variables.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close!

```
// set
$('#item').attr('data-scan', 'set new value');

// get
var dataScan = $('#item').attr('data-scan');
console.log(dataScan); //=> set new value
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably best if you use `.prop()` rather than `.attr()`

```
$(this).parent().prop('data-scan', $(this).attr('id') );
```

As the jQuery api documentation states

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. In addition, .attr() should not be used on
>   plain objects, arrays, the window, or the document. To retrieve and
>   change DOM properties, use the .prop() method.

Comment: Hmmmm... you sure you have this right? My understanding is the `prop` is for properties of objects such as `selectedIndex` and `tagName`. where as `attr` should be used for attributes, such as `data-scan`

Comment: Seems I am correct, [here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/AzDQm/) - unfortunately, for you, I must vote this answer down because it doesn't work